# Non-Adjacent Combinations of Two Words

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the following code in IDLE Python 3.9 the expected output was coming but when I run the code in code playground (Online IDE) the code was not showing expected output but instead throwing some error.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    non_adjacent(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

The code:

```py
     def non_adjacent(words:str):
        words_list = words.split()
            result = []
            l = len(words_list)
            for i in range(l-2):
                for j in range(i+2, l):
                    tmp1 = words_list[i]
                    tmp2 = words_list[j]
                    index_tmp1 = [k for k in range(l) if words_list[k]==tmp1]
                    index_tmp2 = [m for m in range(l) if words_list[m]==tmp2]
                    not_adj = True
                    for el1 in index_tmp1:
                        for el2 in index_tmp2:
                            if abs(el1 - el2) == 1:
                                not_adj = False
                    tmp = sorted([tmp1, tmp2])
                    if tmp not in result and not_adj:
                        result.append(tmp)
            for el in sorted(result):
                print(*el)
        while True:
            non_adjacent(input())
```

Comment: Anybody please help me

Comment: Anybody Please help me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To host it online, you will need to use repl.it, I dont know if code playground supports input(), anyways goto repl.it and create an account. then a new repl. Then choose "Python" and give it a name. then post this code:

```py
def non_adjacent(words:str):


    words_list = words.split()
    result = []
    l = len(words_list)
    for i in range(l-2):
        for j in range(i+2, l):
            tmp1 = words_list[i]
            tmp2 = words_list[j]
            index_tmp1 = [k for k in range(l) if words_list[k]==tmp1]
            index_tmp2 = [m for m in range(l) if words_list[m]==tmp2]
            not_adj = True
            for el1 in index_tmp1:
                for el2 in index_tmp2:
                    if abs(el1 - el2) == 1:
                        not_adj = False
            tmp = sorted([tmp1, tmp2])
            if tmp not in result and not_adj:
                result.append(tmp)
    for el in sorted(result):
        print(*el)




while True:
    non_adjacent(input("Please enter words sperated by a space: "))
```

Working Example:
https://replit.com/@craftit7/EmailHelp1#main.py

Comment: At in code playground output was coming but extra the error was coming sir

Comment: Ok sure i will try to help

Comment: replit.com here output was coming sir but at in my code playground output was coming but error is showing along with output sir

Answer (score 0):

EOFError is raised when one of the built-in functions input() or raw_input() hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading any data. This error is sometimes experienced while using online IDEs. This occurs when we have asked the user for input but have not provided any input in the input box.

Code playground is an online IDE.

Comment: How i can run this code in code play ground sir. I want to run this code in code playground sir

Comment: Sir please change the code and give me the code to be runable in code playground sir

Comment: I will try my best.

Comment: Ok sir. Please hep me sir